# Asset catalog vs folder reference: When to use one or the other?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can put files into `Assets.xcassets` or I can put files into folder references (the blue folders). When would I choose one over the other?

Comment: you should of course use assets since from iOS 9, App-slicing has been introduced which allows you to serve specific size assets to different devices therefore reducing app size and download bandwidth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably use asset catalogs as that's what Apple wants you to use going forward (the tools will reflect that) and they bring many advantages:

- App thinning
- Setting asset properties without code, e.g., rendering mode or slicing
- You don't have to remember naming conventions like `@2x`, `~ipad`, `-568` etc to get device-specific assets automatically
- Asset catalogs will point out missing assets if you tick the right boxes for the versions and devices you support, and they provide a nice overview
- You should get used to them as some platforms (e.g., watchOS) require you to use asset catalogs

There are a few caveats:

- If you deploy back to iOS 6, some features [don't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900967/asset-catalogs-in-resource-bundles/28568073#28568073) – asset catalogs still help to organize your assets, but the runtime features won't work as Xcode will just dump plain image files into your bundle.
- If you deploy to iOS 7 or later, Xcode will compile all assets into one `.car` file (that's the whole idea). However, this can be harder to debug because you cannot look into the compiled file, and it also means you cannot simply get a file URL from a single asset. To create a file URL, you always have to load the asset (by its name) and write it to disk first. `*`
- The last point also implies that you cannot use the `NSBundle` (in Swift 3.0: `Bundle`) APIs to retrieve URLs or paths to image files. In order to load assets from a bundle other than the main bundle, you rely on Apple to provide an API, [which they do since iOS 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30312469/2050985). If you organize shared code in resource bundles and deploy to iOS 7 or earlier, you shouldn't use asset catalogs. This is probably mostly relevant if you intend to develop a framework.

`*` E.g., the CoreSpotlight API allows you to set a [`thumbnailURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet/thumbnailURL), but if your image is within an asset catalog, you must either write it to disk separately yourself, or use the [`thumbnailData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet/thumbnailData) property. If you had a file URL to begin with, you'd never have to load the asset into memory. I'm not sure if Spotlight could access file URLs from within your app bundle. It's just an example.

Comment: How about localization for images? I see button "Localize..." for the .png files stored in folders, but there is no button like that for images added to .xcassets.
Hope I just don't know where to look for it

Answer (score 1):

You should use Assets. Many benefits the folder references can't do

1) Change color of image without any code

2) Support vector, pdf better.

3) Support `Slicing image`.

[image]

4) Manage resource easier for autolayout. If your resources has 1x, 2x, 3x and `ipad image size != iphone image size`, you can add 6 files into 1 asset item.

You can read more here
http://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know