# UIImageView Images Appear in my Storyboards or at Runtime but Not Both

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder

I have added some UIImageViews and set their Images in the Xcode Storyboard Editor.

My images are located in folder references (blue folders). For example, Icons/mini-10.png.

If I set the path in the storyboard editor to `mini-10.png` then it shows up in the editor but not at runtime. And I get a runtime error `Could not load the "mini-10.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier`.

If I set the path to `Icons/mini-10.png` then it shows up at runtime but not in the editor.

Comment: why are you adding images in the folder? Better add your all images in .xcassets folder available in Xcode project. please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117076/asset-catalog-vs-folder-reference-when-to-use-one-or-the-other

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight. It's working much better now.